# Разделять ли скрипт на модули?

Tags: python

Пишу программу для КПК. Программа очень большая (аналог комповской IDLE)... Возник вопрос: целесообразно ли разделять ли скрипт на модули? С точки зрения дальнейшего совершенствования и сопровождения программы, я понимаю, что так намного удобнее, но вот с точки зрения скорости загрузки... Что быстрее: цельный скрипт или поделенный, скажем, на десяток модулей?

Answer (score 3):

- Идея по поводу организации всей системы в одном файле - это `100%` случай [`premature optimization`.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)

> - Вы пытаетесь выиграть время в загрузке модулей **еще не существующей** *(или не до конца функционирующей)* программы. Если у вас будет хорошая, корректно работающая, оттестированная программа, то только тогда можно говорить об оптимизации.
> - По собственному опыту, *"узкие места"* обычно проявляются совсем не там, где ты их ожидаешь, поэтому говорить о производительности, не имея под рукой результатов `profiler'а` - это бессмысленно. Тем более, что ради этого вы собираетесь пожертвовать простотой сопровождения и рефакторинга вашего продукта.

- Ваша **оптимизация** на деле может спокойно оказаться **пессимизацией.**

> - Лично я не уверен, что подход *"один большой файл без импортов несистемных модулей"* лучше в плане производительности, нежели подход с некоторым количеством модулей. Ведь фактически вы говорите: `"Загрузи мне все зависимости сразу и не выгружай до завершения работы."`
> - С учетом того, что вы разрабатываете под мобильную платформу, вы вполне можете упереться в ограничения, накладываемые ей. `Python` потенциально может не подгружать модули до того момента, пока они действительно не оказываются необходимыми, а вы своим решением сразу же запрещаете такой подход.
> - Хотя, разумеется, для того, чтобы говорить что-либо строго, здесь, помимо обычного `python interpreter pipeline,` нужно быть знакомым с особенностями платформы, на которой вы разворачиваете ваш продукт, и, собственно, с особенностями используемой имплементации `python`.

- На тот случай, если в какой-то момент вы действительно упретесь в скорость работы `import'ов,` есть несколько простых и эффективных решений:

> - Выполнять `lazy imports` на уровне функций, которые используют соответствующие модули *( см. **[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128478/should-python-import-statements-always-be-at-the-top-of-a-module)** и **[[2]](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2008-October/002207.html)** )*
> - Воспользоваться каким-либо [готовым решением](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473888-lazy-module-imports/) для глобального применения подхода `lazy imports`.
> - Добавить к финальной сборке программы постпроцессинговый шаг, который будет в релизной конфигурации *"схлопывать"* все имеющиеся модули, скажем, в один большой скрипт.